# How do I make a popup over a pin on a static Google map?

Tags: google-maps

I used the Google Maps API to render a static map with pins on it.

Image [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=700x600&scale=2&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:A%7CChiang%20Mai,Thailand&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:F%7CKathmandu,Nepal&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:E%7CNamangaKenya&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:I%7CPerth,Australia&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:C%7CHanoi,Vietnam&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:D%7CCalcutta,India&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:H%7CNauru&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:B%7CGili%20Air&markers=color:0xE59BE2%7Clabel:G%7CManus).

Is there a way to make a popup for the pins like on the standard Google Maps (where you can normally scroll around)?

It's on a WordPress page: http://clairepyper.org/ The table to the left of the map shows modals on clicking a place name. I'm wondering if there is way to get the modals opening from clicking the markers instead/as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function init_map(){
   var myOptions = {
      zoom:14,
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.26489,-74.533312),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.26489,-74.533312)});
   infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"<b>Lawton's Service Company, LLC</b><br/>400 Mercer St<br /> Hightstown, NJ 08520" });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
   infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

You can add an indefinite number of those markers with a LatLng entry, and it's own little box over it.

(Sorry for the lack of code formatting.  My browser is not showing the cool code tools.)

Comment: Does this work for static images? I'm looking at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial and unsure..

Comment: I don't know what you mean?  Do you mean a custom "pin" graphic?  I don't think so?  Do you mean using your own map image, and putting a pin on that?  Because that definitely will not work.  Sorta defeats the purpose of using the API entirely.

Comment: That thing you linked up there is actually using the API, like I suggested, and using something else (like imageGoo or something) to actually generate the static graphic.  So what you really need to do is combine two technologies together.

Comment: Yes I used the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/). Is there a way to use [the JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) to create a static map? For ease of navigation on the page I don't want to allow for any zooming or panning of the map.